# Minix sys_fork() print message

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I need to print a message that informs the user that a process has been forked from the kernel call sys_fork. 
I added the command `printf("process forked\n");` in the sys_fork() function but nothing happened. 
Is this correct or do I have to do something else? Any help?

the code is

```
#include "syslib.h"

PUBLIC int sys_fork(parent, child, child_endpoint, map_ptr, flags, msgaddr)
endpoint_t parent;      /* process doing the fork */
endpoint_t child;       /* which proc has been created by the fork */
endpoint_t *child_endpoint;
struct mem_map *map_ptr;
u32_t flags;
vir_bytes *msgaddr;
{
/* A process has forked.  Tell the kernel. */

  message m;
  int r;

  m.PR_ENDPT = parent;
  m.PR_SLOT = child;
  m.PR_MEM_PTR = (char *) map_ptr;
  m.PR_FORK_FLAGS = flags;
  r = _kernel_call(SYS_FORK, &m);
  *child_endpoint = m.PR_ENDPT;
  *msgaddr = (vir_bytes) m.PR_FORK_MSGADDR;

  printf("process forked\n"); //the modification I made

  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi anna_jennifer from CEID!

you have to put the printf inside /kernel/system/do_fork.c and before return OK;

Comment: Σε ευχαριστώ πολύ συνάδελφε!! =D

Comment: Αν καταφέρεις και λύσεις το 3 ρίξε κανα tip :P

Comment: χαχα χλωμο το βλεπω να το λυνω.. :P

Comment: @anna_jennifer procs_in_use,mp_child_utime & mp_child_stime ;)

Comment: εχεις κανει το 5a;

Comment: ναι..τροποποιεις το system call do_stat για να εμφανισει το v_inode_nr...το προβλημα τωρα ειναι το 5β που μαλλον δεν θα το κανω :P

Comment: @anna και πως περνας μεσα τον parameter που θες;(filename) σου λεει να φτιάξεις εσύ system call..στο πέρνει σωστό ο grader;

Comment: το περνας μεσω message.. ναι